# Android Radio buttons do nothing on click

Tags: java, android, radio-button

Is there a way to make radio buttons do nothing when they are clicked? I am trying to make a Score Board and need a way to show the periods/halves/quarters ect. The radio buttons will be selected by the program to display periods/halves/quarters ect. Is this a good way to do it or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `clickable` attribute for `View`s

> Defines whether this view reacts to click events.
>
> Must be a boolean value, either "true" or "false".

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:clickable

Answer (score 0):

If the user doesn't ever need to click the radio buttons (ie if its always controlled by the program), why don't you just use images instead of radio buttons.

The benefits of using images for this are...

- Images aren't clickable by default
- It'll look nicer (you can make the Images look like a real scoreboard)
- It doesn't rely on the default Android appearance (which is different for each phone)